# Supabase SQL Database Functions and Parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, curl, supabase, supabase-database

In my supabase database, I have a list of words along with their uuids in the form of

| uuid | word | unique_chars | found_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | apple | 4 | 0 |
| y2 | banana | 3 | 0 |

I want to return all words, which contain a specific letter – say `"E"` (called "main char") – from the table. Therefore, I tried using an SQL Database Function like this:

```
create or replace function get_possible_words()
returns setof dict
language sql
as $$
  select *
  from dict
  where word ilike (%e%)
$$;
```

which works perfectly fine and would return `"apple"`.

However, when trying to pass the letter `"E"` (`"main char"`) as a parameter, it is not working anymore, whatever I try:

```
## Get Results (Supabase)
curl -X "POST" "https://abc.supabase.co/rest/v1/rpc/get_possible_words" \
     -H 'apikey: key' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
     -d $'{
  "mainchar": "E"
}'
```

together with a slightly altered version of the function

```
create or replace function get_possible_words(mainchar text)
returns setof dict
language sql
as $$
  select *
  from dict
  where word like (mainchar)
$$;
```

does not work. Another attempt was

```
drop function if exists test_query;
create function test_query (parameter text)
RETURNS TABLE(uuid uuid, word text) AS
$$
BEGIN
  return query SELECT uuid, word FROM "dict"
    INNER JOIN "word" ON "dict".column = "word".column 
    WHERE "word".column = parameter;
END;
$$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

which did not work as well ("`relation "word" does not exist`"). Could someone please help me out with the syntax? Thanks a lot and all the best from Germany!

Comment: Hey any luck on this? New to the syntax here and getting null returned, running locally.

Answer (score 1):

Would this do it?

```sql
create or replace function get_possible_words(mainchar text)
returns setof dict
language sql
as $$
  select *
  from dict
  where word ilike (mainchar)
$$;
```

```
curl -X "POST" "https://abc.supabase.co/rest/v1/rpc/get_possible_words" \
     -H 'apikey: key' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
     -d $'{
  "mainchar": "%e%"
}'
```